# "Die Wassermänner hüpfen!" im Hochdeutschen?

Tags: standard-german, bavarian

Gibt es den Ausdruck "Die Wassermänner hüpfen!" im Hochdeutschen?

Ich kenne den bayerischen Ausdruck "D'Wossamandln hupfan!", welcher benutzt wird um sehr starken Regen anzudeuten.

Comment: Ist das ein gebräuchlicher Ausdruck? Ich konnte nichts dazu finden. Ist die Frage nicht auch falsch gestellt? Also eher, ob es die Redewendung außerhalb des bayrischen Sprachraums bekannt/gebräuchlich ist (vgl Samstag/Sonnabend). Den Ausdruck an sich gibt es natürlich im Hochdeutschen, wenn man so will. Ist ja ein normaler Satz.

Comment: Ich würde eher sagen, dass ich den Ausdruck mehr von älteren Generationen kenne.  In meiner niederbayerischen Gegend wird aber durchaus den meisten als bekannt gelten.
Ja, man könnte die Frage auch so stellen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Gibt es den Ausdruck "Die Wassermänner hüpfen!" im Hochdeutschen?

Nein, den gibt es spezifisch für diesen Kontext im Hochdeutschen nicht.

> Ich kenne den bayerischen Ausdruck "D'Wossamandln hupfan!", welcher benutzt wird um sehr starken Regen anzudeuten.

Auch wenn ich als Oberbayer diesen Ausdruck noch nie gehört habe, kann ich mir vorstellen was damit sinnbildlich gemeint ist:

Es beschreibt wie die Regentropfen auf den Boden treffen, und hüpfen  um in weitere Tropfen zu zerspringen, die bei ganz starkem Regen nach oben spritzen. Die Tropfen, die nach oben spritzen (*hupfan*), sind die Wassermänner  (*Wossamandln*).

Ein schönes Bild.

Comment: Ich denke ich würde den Ursprung im Niederbayerischen ansiedeln. Und hier wohl auch weniger im modernen Sprachgebrauch als im Altniederbayerischen. Vielleicht ein Idiom, das vom Aussterben bedroht ist?

Comment: @letsfetz Könnte gut sein.

Comment: Die hochdeutsche Version mit dem Wort "Wassermann" gibt dem Satz allerdings eine ganz andere Bedeutung als der bayerischen Ausdruck beabsichtigt. Ein "Mandl" ist doch eher ein Männchen oder ein "wie ein kleines Männchen geformtes Gebilde" Vgl. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mandl .

Comment: @PaulFrost Es gibt keine _hochdeutsche Version_.

Comment: Genau das wollte ich sagen: Die Übertragung ins Hochdeutsche ergibt keinen Sinn bzw. würde den Sinn unkenntlich machen (und daher wird sie auch nicht verwendet).

Comment: @Paul Na ja, man könnte ja auch hochdeutsch sagen _"Die Wassermännchen hüpfen."_  Aber das ist schlicht und einfach nicht üblich um Starkregen zu indizieren.

Answer (score 1):

Wie schon von πάντα ῥεῖ ausgeführt, gibt es den Ausdruck "Die Wassermänner hüpfen" nicht im Hochdeutschen. Er wäre auch irreführend, weil ein *Wassermann* bekanntlich ein männlicher Wassergeist ist. Ein *Mandl* ist jedoch ein Männchen oder ein wie ein kleines Männchen geformtes Gebilde Vgl. [hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mandl). Aber auch die Version "Die Wassermännchen hüpfen" ist unbekannt, wie πάντα ῥεῖ kommentiert.

Eine Google-Suche scheint die Vermutung von letsfetz im Hinblick auf den niederbayerischen Ursprung zu bestätigen und gibt auch gleich eine genaue Erklärung. [Zitat](https://regiowiki.pnp.de/wiki/Wossamandl) aus dem RegioWiki Niederbayern:

> Ein Wossamandl (Wossa-Mandl: "Wassermännchen") nennt man den Spritzer, wenn ein großer Regentropfen auf eine glatte Wasserfläche trifft.
>
> Beispiel: Do howe scho gseng wia im Weia d'Wossamandl ghupft san. ("Und ich bemerkte, dass die ersten Wassertropfen auf die Wasseroberfläche des Teichs trafen.

Allerdings scheint der Ausdruck auch in Österreich vorzukommen. Hier ein [Video](https://gramho.com/media/1788447237892521037) mit dem Titel "Wenn de Wossamandl wieder ins klare Gebirgswassal köpfeln". Der Beitrag stammt jedenfalls von einer Österreicherin.

Eine ganz andere Spur führt ebenfalls nach Österreich. Als [Wossamandl](http://old.hohetauern.at/mundart/begriffe-ansehen/7861-wossamandl.html) wird laut  der Dialektplattform des Nationalparks Hohe Tauern ein schwarzer Salamander bezeichnet, der nur nach Regenfällen auf Wegen zu sehen ist. Dass die Tiere dann hüpfen, bezweifle ich aber.

Answer (score 0):

Nein, nicht wirklich. Eher sprechen wir (Südniedersachsen) von "Regen wie aus Eimern/Kübeln", oder es "regnet wie hulle" ("wie hulle" hat die Bedeutung von "sehr stark"). Den Ausdruck von "hüpfenden Wassermännern" habe ich jetzt zum ersten Mal gehört. Vielleicht wird er in Bayern auch in seiner hochdeutschen Form verwendet, weil die diese Floskel dort üblich ist, aber wie gesagt denke ich nicht, dass sie ihren Weg ins allgemeine Hochdeutsch gefunden hat.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please refrain from listing other alternative expressions, because they are not relevant to this question and answer.